# Using objects to store a list of names

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I was wondering how to use an object to store a list of different names and access them by simply using the key.
Do I have to use embedded object like this.

```
var f = 
{ 
    0 : { name : "John" }, 
    1 : { name : "Phillip" }
};
console.log(f[1].name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not over-complicate things. Why don't you just try a simple array?

```
var f = [
    { name : "John" }, 
    { name : "Phillip" }
];
console.log(f[1].name);
```

Comment: Why didn't you use square brakets within the array like [ name : "John" ], but {} ?

Comment: @user2646855 because it is an array of objects. that way you can add more useful properties to your "Person objects" like this: `{ name : "John", age: 21 }`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just an array, which is indexed identically? Do you actually *need* a `name:` attribute for some reason?

```
var names = [ 'John', 'Phillip' ];
```

Instead of `names[0].name`, which is pretty redundant, you'd just use `names[0]`...

Comment: If the only properties of your object are `name`, then this is much simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

He wants to access them by key:

```
var people = {
    John:{ age:33},
    Bob :{ age:42}
};
```

Now you can truly access them by key:

```
console.log(people["John"].age);
```

or this way (although odd):

```
console.log(people.John.age);
```

No looping is necessary, you are using the power of javascripts associative syntax to index directly into your data structure.  No need to refer to some arbitrary integer index either.

This definitely works but typically you'd use a more appropriate property to index than just a name like perhaps an employee id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
Var names = [
      { 'name' : 'ashwin', age: 18 },
      {'name' : 'jhon', 'age' : 20 }
];

console.log (  names[0].name );
```